# For loop concatenates only last iteration. Why?

Tags: r, for-loop, concatenation

I want a vector with the excel-letters: c(A, B, C, ... Z, AA, AB, ... AZ, BA, ...).

My try was this:

```
excel_letters <- LETTERS

for(n in length(LETTERS)){

  excel_letters <- c(excel_letters, paste0(LETTERS[n], LETTERS))

}
```

Since i am defining excel_letters outside of the loop before iterating through the loop, i expected to get the wanted output. Instead i am only getting:

```
 [1] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  "K"  "L"  "M"  "N"  "O"  "P"  "Q"  "R"  "S"  "T"  "U"  "V"  "W"  "X"  "Y"  "Z"  "ZA" "ZB" "ZC"
[30] "ZD" "ZE" "ZF" "ZG" "ZH" "ZI" "ZJ" "ZK" "ZL" "ZM" "ZN" "ZO" "ZP" "ZQ" "ZR" "ZS" "ZT" "ZU" "ZV" "ZW" "ZX" "ZY" "ZZ"
```

Which is basically LETTERS plus the last iteration.

What am i missing here?

I know there are other approaches to this but i wanna know why this specifically doesn't work.

Comment: you need `for(n in 1:length(LETTERS))` or better still `for(n in seq_along(LETTERS))`.  At the moment `n` only every takes the value `length(LETTERS)` rather than the sequence.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva Or better yet `for (letter in letters)`. Or better yet, avoid the entire loop and construct the vector directly as `paste0(rep(LETTERS, each = length(LETTERS)), LETTERS)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, `length(LETTERS)` is a single element, so `for (n in length(LETTERS))` iterates over a single value.

In general you rarely need to iterate over indices — it’s easier to iterate over the values in your vector directly:

```
for (letter in LETTERS) …
```

In the rare event where you *really* need to iterate over the indices of a vector (which you don’t need here), use the pattern

```
for (i in seq_along(the_vector))
```

… but for your use-case, a better (shorter, more expressive, more efficient) solution avoids the loop entirely, in favour of direct construction:

```
excel_letters <- paste0(rep(c("", LETTERS), each = length(LETTERS)), LETTERS)
```

The more you write R the more you will discover how vectorisation and bespoke algorithms allow you to avoid loops.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have to  admit; it was a silly mistake that i simply overlooked. I will study your recommended solution to hopefully write better r code in the future!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the range that the for loop is iterating over:

```
for(n in length(LETTERS)){
  print(n)
}
# [1] 26
```

The range needs to be `1:length(LETTERS)`:

```
for(n in 1:length(LETTERS)){
  excel_letters <- c(excel_letters, paste0(LETTERS[n], LETTERS))
}
 [1] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  "K"  "L"  "M"  "N"  "O" 
 [16] "P"  "Q"  "R"  "S"  "T"  "U"  "V"  "W"  "X"  "Y"  "Z"  "AA" "AB" "AC" "AD"
 [31] "AE" "AF" "AG" "AH" "AI" "AJ" "AK" "AL" "AM" "AN" "AO" "AP" "AQ" "AR" "AS"
 [46] "AT" "AU" "AV" "AW" "AX" "AY" "AZ" "BA" "BB" "BC" "BD" "BE" "BF" "BG" "BH"
 etc.
```

Other ways of doing the same thing:

1. use map (e.g. `c(excel_letters, unlist(map(1:26, ~ paste0(excel_letters[.x], excel_letters))))`)
2. use `seq_along(LETTERS)` instead of `1:length(LETTERS)` (credit: Konrad)

Comment: Using `1:length(x)` is error-prone (check what happens if `x` is empty) and should be completely avoided. Use `seq_along(x)` if your really need to iterate over indices (which you don’t need here).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have to admit; it was a silly mistake that i simply overlooked. I will study your recommended solution to hopefully write better r code in the future, but have to say that it looks much more complicated than Konrads solution. But i think i can learn a lot here anyways.